# How to generate an external downloadlink for files

Tags: apex, attachment, files, contentdocumentlink, file-sharing

I have created a visualforce page (site) with a dowloadlink from files. I can use this when I am logged in into Salesforce. I want to achieve this for external users by a site. In salesforce It is possible to generate a external link on the attachment. How do I create a this shared link trough apex.

Below is how I currently generate the link url:

```
    public with sharing class AttachmentfilesExt{
    public List<ContentDocumentLink> idsContentdocument {get;set;}
    public AttachmentfilesExt(Apexpages.StandardController con){
        idsContentdocument = new List<ContentDocumentLink>();
        Id accId  = [SELECT id , Token__c FROM Account WHERE Token__c =:apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('token') LIMIT 1].id;
        system.debug('accId: '+ accId);
        idsContentdocument = [SELECT ContentDocument.title, ContentDocumentId,Id,LinkedEntityId,ShareType FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId = :accId];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try to use this approach:

```
 public static String documentDownloadUrl() {
    ContentDocumentLink cdl = //You get in your own way
    return Url.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()
                        + '/sfc/servlet.shepherd/document/download/' 
                        + cdl.ContentDocumentId;
}
```